# npm install failed deprecated core.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I try to run npm install on my project i get an error , the same command npm install was running in last february whitout issue now I get an error that core.js@2.6.11 and  request@2.88.2 are deprecated

I tried some clean cache and install new latest angular cli but still still failed

Here's the log error :

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for regenerate-unicode-properties@^8.2.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'regexpu-core'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Here's my dependencies list :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@idemia/ams-ui": "file:idemia-ams-ui-1.1.4-RC1.tgz",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cdk-table-exporter": "^1.2.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "daemonite-material": "^4.1.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mat-select-autocomplete": "^1.3.0",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.11",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.2",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.3",
    "regenerate-unicode-properties": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

Comment: Try removing ```"package-lock.json"``` and then run ```"npm install && npm update"```,..

Comment: still have the same error :(

Comment: Decoding your error log, it seems that the error lies in regexpu-core having an outdated dependency. In your package.json, can you comment out regenerate-unicode-properties (of course, delete your package-lock first) and see if the project builds? Reading your error logs, this is the best solution I can think of at the moment.

Comment: The probleme is that there's no regenerate-unicode-properties@^8.2.0 in teh npm repository